Automation of Python Scripts in AWS Sagemaker
I have built a pipelines to do ETL and run DeepAR model in Sagemaker but I realised the process of automation is so complicated for data science projects.
I have looked into StepFunction as well but why there is "StartNotebookInstance" without any component to run notebook or anything?
Is there a way to automate the python code that I have written within the notebook instance that I have created with lifecycle configuration (additional packages installed)?
I am aware there were code pipelines but it would be deprecated soon.
Many thanks.
